# JAX-WS handling incompatibility issue between Eclipse and Netbeans

Tags: java, eclipse, web-services, netbeans, jax-ws

So I have a Web Service Client that was created in NetBeans 7.1.2 using the GUI Web Service tools, then jarred to be used in an Eclipse project (Eclipse Indigo). Both are using JDK 1.6. The problem is, even when using the exact same code, the two IDE's are using different libraries to handle the web service calls.

Eclipse is using Axis2, which absolutely will not work for this project (no NTLMv2 support)
I'm pretty sure Netbeans is using Java SE 6 internal code, although I'm not 100% sure.

The calls work in Netbeans, but not in Eclipse, where I run into the HttpClient 3.1 issue.

So the question is: How do I force eclipse to use the same library that Netbeans is using to handle the web service calls. I do have access to the code for the Netbeans project.

I managed to generate an error in Netbeans that matches the ones I'm getting in eclipse, so here are the two stack traces:

Eclipse:

```
javax.xml.ws.WebServiceException: org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: Transport error: 401 Error: Unauthorized
at org.apache.axis2.jaxws.ExceptionFactory.createWebServiceException(ExceptionFactory.java:175)
at org.apache.axis2.jaxws.ExceptionFactory.makeWebServiceException(ExceptionFactory.java:70)
at org.apache.axis2.jaxws.ExceptionFactory.makeWebServiceException(ExceptionFactory.java:128)
at org.apache.axis2.jaxws.core.controller.impl.AxisInvocationController.execute(AxisInvocationController.java:559)
at org.apache.axis2.jaxws.core.controller.impl.AxisInvocationController.doInvoke(AxisInvocationController.java:118)
at org.apache.axis2.jaxws.core.controller.impl.InvocationControllerImpl.invoke(InvocationControllerImpl.java:82)
at org.apache.axis2.jaxws.client.proxy.JAXWSProxyHandler.invokeSEIMethod(JAXWSProxyHandler.java:317)
at org.apache.axis2.jaxws.client.proxy.JAXWSProxyHandler.invoke(JAXWSProxyHandler.java:159)
at $Proxy16.addList(Unknown Source)
at com.jnl.mktsys.sharepoint.JLists.addList(JLists.java:109)
at com.jackson.mktsys.wholesaler.document.document.jawscontract.DocumentContractImpl.createSite(DocumentContractImpl.java:212)
at com.jackson.mktsys.wholesaler.document.document.jawscontract.DocumentContractImpl.createDocument(DocumentContractImpl.java:39)
at com.jackson.mktsys.wholesaler.document.document.test.DocumentContractImplCreateTest.testCreateExist(DocumentContractImplCreateTest.java:53)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at junit.framework.TestCase.runTest(TestCase.java:168)
at junit.framework.TestCase.runBare(TestCase.java:134)
at junit.framework.TestResult$1.protect(TestResult.java:110)
at junit.framework.TestResult.runProtected(TestResult.java:128)
at junit.framework.TestResult.run(TestResult.java:113)
at junit.framework.TestCase.run(TestCase.java:124)
at junit.framework.TestSuite.runTest(TestSuite.java:243)
at junit.framework.TestSuite.run(TestSuite.java:238)
at org.junit.internal.runners.JUnit38ClassRunner.run(JUnit38ClassRunner.java:83)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:50)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:467)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:683)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:390)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:197)
Caused by: org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: Transport error: 401 Error: Unauthorized
at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.HTTPSender.handleResponse(HTTPSender.java:295)
at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.HTTPSender.sendViaPost(HTTPSender.java:190)
at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.HTTPSender.send(HTTPSender.java:75)
at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.CommonsHTTPTransportSender.writeMessageWithCommons(CommonsHTTPTransportSender.java:389)
at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.CommonsHTTPTransportSender.invoke(CommonsHTTPTransportSender.java:222)
at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.send(AxisEngine.java:435)
at org.apache.axis2.description.OutInAxisOperationClient.send(OutInAxisOperation.java:402)
at org.apache.axis2.description.OutInAxisOperationClient.executeImpl(OutInAxisOperation.java:229)
at org.apache.axis2.client.OperationClient.execute(OperationClient.java:165)
at org.apache.axis2.jaxws.core.controller.impl.AxisInvocationController.execute(AxisInvocationController.java:554)
... 28 more
```

Netbeans:

```
com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.ClientTransportException: The server sent HTTP status code 401: Unauthorized
at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.transport.http.client.HttpTransportPipe.checkStatusCode(HttpTransportPipe.java:296)
at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.transport.http.client.HttpTransportPipe.createResponsePacket(HttpTransportPipe.java:245)
at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.transport.http.client.HttpTransportPipe.process(HttpTransportPipe.java:203)
at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.transport.http.client.HttpTransportPipe.processRequest(HttpTransportPipe.java:122)
at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.transport.DeferredTransportPipe.processRequest(DeferredTransportPipe.java:123)
at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.__doRun(Fiber.java:626)
at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.api.pipe.Fiber._doRun(Fiber.java:585)
at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.doRun(Fiber.java:570)
at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.runSync(Fiber.java:467)
at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.Stub.process(Stub.java:308)
at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.sei.SEIStub.doProcess(SEIStub.java:146)
at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.sei.SyncMethodHandler.invoke(SyncMethodHandler.java:98)
at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.sei.SyncMethodHandler.invoke(SyncMethodHandler.java:78)
at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.sei.SEIStub.invoke(SEIStub.java:129)
at $Proxy30.addList(Unknown Source)
at com.jnl.mktsys.sharepoint.JLists.addList(JLists.java:109)
at Test.createSite(Test.java:36)
at Test.main(Test.java:24)
```

Comment: Did you check the jars by right click project? Make sure you have only required jars

Comment: The problem is, my ivy dependencies require Axis2, so I'm stuck having it in my project.

Comment: Apparently there are ways to exclude dependencies in the ivy.xml file. I was not aware of this. Problem solved.